# I can't use both of the Xbox 360 gamepad's analog triggers at the same time in my game

Tags: unity, javascript, joystick

I am using a Xbox 360 controller on my Windows computer, with this control scheme:

- Squeezing LT aims down the sights of the weapon
- Squeezing RT shoots the weapon

Each of these actions works individually, but whenever I try to shoot while aiming (ie. squeezing both triggers at once), it just lowers the gun.

I know that it has to do with the fact that LT and RT are read as the positive and negative ends of the 3rd joystick axis in Unity, but is there a way to fix this? I am using javascript if it requires scripting.

Answer (score 2):

#### *"3rd Axis"* represents the two triggers, together. Use *"9th Axis"* and *"10th Axis"* to reference them, individually.

I am going to assume you refer to [the previous question you asked](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128596/), in how to reference the Xbox controller. While the answer provided by Philipp gives you insight, it does not give you the actual answer; it only gives you the *almost* identical interpretation of the particular system application.

In Unity, you can reference both triggers as "3rd Axis". As you have found out, you can not have a single axis representing "true" for both sides. It would be like having a single analog stick that is both *up* and *down* at the same time. It is logically impossible.

Alternatively, you can reference ***LT*** as `9th Axis` and ***RT*** as `10th Axis`. Referencing them *separately*, you can have both triggers operate independently.

As I addressed in answering your other question, it is worth pointing out that these buttons ***must*** be referenced as *axis*. This means you use `InputManager` to register them, and call them as `Input.GetAxis()`. This is because the triggers are *not* basic buttons. They interpet pressure, so rather than turning *on* and *off*, they start at *0* and move to *1*. In other words, you could register a `0.5` by pressing the trigger in half way.

Comment: @TheMattBat999, if this solved your problem, please accept the answer so that other users know you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the LT and RT buttons not working simultaneously if you have this problem checkout my reddit post
here the link: https://www.reddit.com/user/Qosh_manuel/

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer, linking to a link-only answer. This puts it at high risk of link rot, where the chain of links eventually points nowhere. To avoid this, try editing your question to include a description of the actual solution, not just a link to where to find it. (You can still include a link to credit the sources that helped you, while preserving the information from rotting away)